# How to create SOAP Request , the easy way

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, jaxb

I am new to SOAP,
I am hardcoding the SOAP Request and sending to server,its working fine.Now i want to create SOAP Request Dynamically, as i am new to SOAP , i have no Idea
 To prepare XML i use jaxb , should i use the same to creating SOAP Request or is there any better approach?

My Java Code

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String xml ="<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
            + "   <soapenv:Header/>\n"
            + "   <soapenv:Body>\n"
            + "      <tem:RequestData>\n"
            + "         <!--Optional:-->\n"
            + "         <tem:requestDocument>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "\n"
            + "<![CDATA[ <Request>\n"
            + "<Authentication CMId='68' Guid='5594FB83-F4D4-431F-B3C5-EA6D7A8BA795' Password='poihg321TR' Function='1' />\n"
            + "<Establishment Id='4297867' >\n"
            + "</Establishment>\n"
            + "</Request> ]]> \n"
            + "\n"
            + "\n"
            + "</tem:requestDocument>\n"
            + "      </tem:RequestData>\n"
            + "   </soapenv:Body>\n"
            + "</soapenv:Envelope>";




    sendRequestToChannel(xml);
}

private static String sendRequestToChannel(String request) {

    String xmlData = null;
    BufferedReader rd = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    String line = null;
    String lineSep = null;
    String data = null;
    StringBuffer serverData = null;
    int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 6000, PORT = 80;
    String HOST = null,PATH=null;


    try {

        java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://pp.hotels.travelrepublic.co.uk/ChannelManager.svc");
        HOST=url.getHost();
        PATH=url.getPath();
        Socket cliSocket = new Socket();
        cliSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT), SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(cliSocket.getOutputStream()));

        bw.write("POST " + PATH + " HTTP/1.0");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write("Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write("SOAPAction: http://tempuri.org/IPublicChannelManagerService/RequestData");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write("Content-Length: " + request.length() + "\r\n");
        bw.write("Host: " + HOST + "\r\n");
        bw.write("Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
        bw.write("User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)\r\n");
        bw.write("\r\n");
        bw.write(request);
        bw.flush();

        rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cliSocket.getInputStream()));

        serverData = new StringBuffer("");

        lineSep = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            serverData.append(line);
            serverData.append(lineSep);
        }

        data = serverData.toString();

        int index = data.indexOf("<");

        if (index != -1) {
            xmlData = data.substring(index);
            System.out.println("\r\n \r\n  XML Data \r\n  "+xmlData);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\r\n \r\n  XML Data Not Retrived");
        }


    } catch (java.net.UnknownHostException uh) {
        uh.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel : UnknownHostException " + uh.getMessage());
        return "   in sendRequestToChannel : UnknownHostException " + uh.toString();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel :  IOException " + ioe.getMessage());
        return " in sendRequestToChannel :   IOException " + ioe.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$  in sendRequestToChannel :  Exception " + e.getMessage());
        return " in sendRequestToChannel :  Exception " + e.toString();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        try {
            if (rd != null) {
                rd.close();

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

        bw = null;
        rd = null;
        line = null;
        lineSep = null;
        data = null;
        serverData = null;

    }
    return xmlData;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple frameworks available for this

Please see http://www.javabeat.net/programming-web-services-using-apache-axis/

Answer (score 0):

try using the classes of 'javax.xml.soap' package.

```
public String cretaeSOAPMessage(Document soapBodyDoc, String serverURI,
        String soapAction, String bodyNameSpace) {
    String soapMsg = null;      
    try {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();


        SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody(); 
        soapBody.addNamespaceDeclaration("tem", bodyNameSpace);
        soapBody.addDocument(soapBodyDoc);          


        MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + soapAction);;

        soapMessage.saveChanges();


        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            soapMessage.writeTo(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        soapMsg = new String(out.toByteArray());


    } catch (SOAPException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return soapMsg;
}
```

soapBodyDoc : org.w3c.dom.Document representing data inside

serverURI: your target name space

soapAction: wsdl:operation

bodyNameSpace: "http://tempuri.org/"

cannot say if it is better than JAXB. But in one of your other posts i can see that you are struggling to include CDATA section using JAXB. This logic might help you come out of it.

some times you may face some issues at this point

```
soapBody.addDocument(soapBodyDoc);
```

if so, instead of adding the whole body content as a Document, create the body there itself.
For that use the following code sample

```
SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("RequestData", "tem");
soapBodyElem.addChildElement("requestDocument","tem");

soapBodyElem.addTextNode("<![CDATA[ <Request>....");
```